# Custom cookie sent to browser but not stored

Tags: node.js, api, express, vue.js, cookies

I've tried multiple configuration and read multiple posts about this issue but I'm still lost.

The custom cookie sent by my api server is received by the browser but never stored. And I can't figure out why.

I developed a node/express api server deployed on heroku.

My front-end uses Vuejs and is deployed on firebase.

Here are the code related to my cookie configuration :

SERVER-SIDE

Cors

```
app.use(
    cors({
        origin: 'https://my-app.firebaseapp.com',
        credentials: true,
    exposedHeaders: ['customCookie']
    })
);
```

Set-cookie

```
const cookieOptions = {
    httpOnly: true,
    sameSite: 'None',
    expires: expirationDate,
    secure: true,
    path: '/',
    domain: 'https://my-app.firebaseapp.com',
};

res.cookie('customCookie', 'value', cookieOptions)
```

CLIENT-SIDE

Axios

```
axios.defaults.baseURL = 'https://my-app.herokuapp.com';
axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;
```

REQUEST HEADER

```
POST /auth/sign-in HTTP/1.1
Host: my-app.herokuapp.com
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 55
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
Origin: https://my-app.firebaseapp.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3921.0 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
Accept: */*
Sec-Fetch-Site: cross-site
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Referer: https://my-app.firebaseapp.com/auth/sign-in
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: fr-FR,fr;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7,nl;q=0.6,la;q=0.5
```

RESPONSE HEADER

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: Cowboy
Connection: keep-alive
X-Dns-Prefetch-Control: off
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=15552000; includeSubDomains
X-Download-Options: noopen
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Xss-Protection: 1; mode=block
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://my-app.firebaseapp.com
Vary: Origin, Accept-Encoding
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Expose-Headers: customCookie
Set-Cookie: customCookie=value; Domain=https://my-app.firebaseapp.com; Path=/; Expires=Sun, 17 Nov 2019 11:54:30 GMT; HttpOnly; Secure; SameSite=None
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 200
Etag: W/"c8-qlzfwyZ+uJQMQIeJOQnFSQYPR6o"
Date: Sun, 20 Oct 2019 11:54:30 GMT
Via: 1.1 vegur
```

So, the cookie is correctly sent and received here:

```
Set-Cookie: customCookie=value; Domain=https://my-app.firebaseapp.com; Path=/; Expires=Sun, 17 Nov 2019 11:54:30 GMT; HttpOnly; Secure; SameSite=None
```

But when I check the tab : Google Dev Tools >> Application >> Cookies >> my-app...

=> There is no cookie stored and therefore the cookie is not sent on subsequent request...

Any idea/advice ?

Thank you very much for your help,

Romain

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to handle `Access-Control`.

you can do it by adding this code

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', req.headers.origin);
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With, X-HTTP-Method-Override, Content-Type, Accept');
    next();
});
```

Also, I suppose that you are using Chrome as a browser, can you run chrome without security 
by doing this and then check if your cookies stored or not

> "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"
>   --user-data-dir="C:/Chrome dev session" --args --disable-web-security

Comment: Thanks but the solution you suggested was however already handled bar cors so it was not it... But I've found the issue (see my own answer). Thanks again :)

Answer (score 0):

I think I get it.

In Chrome (and maybe other navigator), cookies seems to be stored only in the domain address and the domain address, in my case, should be the server app (my-app.herokuapp.com), not the client one (my-app.firebaseapp.com).

In other words, I thought my cookie would be stored and visible in my client-app address but they are actually stored and visible on my domain address.

Now everything works...